# Android Fragments bundle getArguments() devuelve null

Tags: android, fragment

Intento pasar un arraylist (que no esta vacío) de un fragmento a otro. Este es el código en el que lo intento pasar a través de los argumentos:

```
Instalaciones_fragment itf = new Instalaciones_fragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();        
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("tipos_instalacion_array_list", arrayTiposInstalaciones);
    itf.setArguments(bundle);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContenedor, new Instalaciones_fragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

y este don intento recuperarlo:

```
Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments != null){
        arrayTiposInstalacion = arguments.getParcelableArrayList("tipos_instalacion_array_list");
    }
```

El problema que tengo es que `arguments` es null. ¿Estoy pasando los argumentos de forma errónea o recuperándolos mal? ¿Alguna solución?

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Para poder pasarlo como parcelable, tu objeto debe implementar parcelable tambien. Si ya estas implementando parcelable en tu objeto, intenta castear el argumento a ArrayList<TuObjeto> al obtenerlo en el Fragment que lo recibe. No te recomiendo implementar serializable por temas de performance.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Ya implemento Parcelable y sto me sigue dando null Bundle arguments = getArguments();, por lo que ya no llega al paso del casto. Alguna otra alternativa por favor?

Comment: Encontre el error, prueba mi respuesta.

Comment: ¡muchas gracias! ¡Funciona!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas inicializando un nuevo `Fragment` despues que haces `setArguments` en una instancia ya creada, por lo tanto `getArguments` te devolvera `null` en tu `Fragment`.

Haces esto:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContenedor, new Instalaciones_fragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

en vez de pasar `itf` que es la instancia de tu `Fragment` con argumentos:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContenedor, itf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

No hace mucho pasaba por la misma situación, lo solucione implementando Serializable al objeto que crear mi ArrayList:

Ejemplo:

```
   Instalaciones_fragment itf = new Instalaciones_fragment();
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putSerializable("keyArrayList", (Serializable) arrayList);
   itf.setArguments(bundle);
```

Ahora para usar la propiedad Serializable necesitas implementarlo en la clase donde crear tu lista enlazada.

Ejemplo:

```
public class Profile implements Serializable {
String first;
String second;
String phone;
String cityAddress;
String cityStreet;

public Student(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4, String s5) {
    this.first = s1;
    this.second = s2;
    this.phone = s3;
    this.cityAddress = s4;
    this.cityStreet = s5;
}
```

}

Por ultimo simplemente obtienes la lista usando este código:

```
ArrayList<Profile> array = (ArrayList<Profile>)extras.getSerializable("keyArrayList");
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Esto me sigue dando null 

Bundle arguments = getArguments();  y así ya no puedo recuperar el serializable. Alguna otra alternativa por favor?